# retry open files in directory

Tags: java, datetime, try-catch

I am trying the following code to open files in a certain directory. The name of the files are assigned by date but some dates are missing. I want to iterate through the dates to get the files and make the code go back 1 day every time it fails to find a file until it finally finds one (`currentdate` is a global variable and the strange xml element is because I'm using processing).

What I think the code should do is:

1. try to open the file with the given date.
2. on error, it goes to catch and gets a new date.
3. the process is repeated until a valid date is found.
4. when a valid date is found it goes to the line where `break` is and exits the loop.

But for some reason it does weird stuff like EDIT # sometimes it jumps too much, especially near the first month #
Is my logic not working for some reason?
Thanks

```
String strdate=getdatestring(counter);
int counter=0;
while(true){
      try{
        xmldata = new XMLElement(this, "dir/" + strdate + "_filename.xml" ); 
        break;
      }catch(NullPointerException e){
        counter +=1;
        strdate=getdatestring(counter);
      }}

String getdatestring(int counter) {
Date firstdate=new Date();
int daystosum=0;
String strcurrentdate="";

if(keyPressed && key=='7'){
  daystosum=-7;
}
daystosum=daystosum-counter;

Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try{
firstdate=formatter.parse("2012-04-13");//first day of the database
}catch(ParseException e){
  println(e);
}
c.setTime(currentdate);
c.add(Calendar.DATE,daystosum);
currentdate=c.getTime();
if(currentdate.before(firstdate)){
  currentdate=firstdate;
}
strcurrentdate=formatter.format(currentdate);

return strcurrentdate;
}
```

Comment: You mean when `firstdate` at this line `firstdate=formatter.parse("2012-04-13");` is in future?

Comment: sorry that problem was actually not real.. i have just edited sorry again. Its strange because in April, which is the first month of files, when i move from may 3rd for example 1 week back to 28th of april, then it goes all the way to the first day of database, 13th of april, but it doesnt misbehave in other months or at least i didnt notice.. im checking for more mistakes but takes a while to load

Comment: I am just trying to understand, which data being in future is causing your issue? In `getdatestring` only external value is firstDate through above line. Am I missing your problem domain?

Comment: Sorry, forget abt the future dates. firstDate never changes, its always "2012-04-13" I move backwards in time by pressing the key ´7´ . And the problem is that when i am near april, for example 3rd of may, and i jump 1 week back - to 28th of april for example, it misses the 28th (ok cuz the file doesnt exist) but then instead of going to 27th which exists, it goes to 13th of april (first day of database)

Comment: Are you just trying to open the latest date available file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe once you do this,

```
          daystosum=daystosum-counter;
```

you need to reset the counter as

```
          counter = 0;
```

otherwise next time it will subtract more bigger number e.g. to start, say `daystosum` is 0 and `counter` is 5, after the `daystosum=daystosum-counter;`, `daystosum` will become `-5`. Again you go in the while loop and file is not found then count will increase to 6. In that case you would be getting `` `daystosum=daystosum-counter; `` as `-5-6 = -11`, but you would want it to move to `-6`. Resetting the counter should ix your issue.

On the other note, I think you can list down the files using `file.listFiles()` from the parent directory and perform the search on the file names. In that case, you are not attempting to open files again and again.

Comment: It was a good hint thanks a lot, i finally solved it, here´s what i did... the problem was quite similar to what u suggested, it was that daystosum had to be added only once... `if(counter==0){
  daystosum=daystosum-counter;
}else{
  daystosum=-counter;
}`

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo: `if(counter==0){ daystosum=daystosum-counter; }` will not do any thing, only else will. so you may write `if(counter!=0){daystosum=-counter; }`. By the way, what is the question here?

Comment: u are right,
  I thought the error was on the try catch with the while loop and the break, im not experienced with java and i thought i had got that wrong but actually the mistake was mine somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo: If you think the answer is helpful, please don't forget to accept. If more question, please do let me know.